# Spring-integration jms

Tags: spring-integration

I am new in spring-integration , I am having problem creating a project with jms , can any one send me the sample project on this and also steps to configure and also run procedure .And also which jms provider I need to install.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the JMS sample under 'basic' here https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples.

The sample uses ActiveMQ so no installation is needed, maven will download it for you.

I also suggest you take a look at the reference http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/